# Disable certain W3C logging fields on Azure App Services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, w3c

When logging web server logs in Azure App Services, every field is logged by default and there doesn't seem to be any way to disable specific fields.

Is there a way around this? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's supported by IIS in applicationhost.config, you can achieve it using an [XDT transform](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples).