# customize the azure app service site access log

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to customize the azure app service site access log-in following format.

#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.0

#Fields: date time s-sitename cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken

we want to remove cs(Referer) from the above log format in IIS. Please help?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `applicationHost.xdt` file to customize w3c logging fields.

**Offical doc:**

[Xdt transform samples](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples)

I am not familiar with that. But I found below post to [Add custom HTTP log fields in Azure web App](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f2a538e3-3461-4132-b9b7-e694d4bfed9e/add-custom-http-log-fields-in-azure-web-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

So if you also not find a right way to remove `(cs)Referer`, maybe you can use `Add` method to rewrite `(cs)Referer` field.

**Related Post:**

[Disable certain W3C logging fields on Azure App Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062220/disable-certain-w3c-logging-fields-on-azure-app-services)