# Enable DEBUG level logs of the Microsoft.AspNetCore namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, azure-web-app-service, log4net

I'm using [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) in my ASP.net Core application, and have the following configurations:

```cs
// Program.cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging((logging) => {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddLog4Net();
        }).UseStartup<Startup>();
```

My config:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%-5date %-5level [%thread] %type.%method:%line - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    
    <!-- log everything coming from AspNetCore -->
    <logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore" additivity="false">
        <level value="Debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </logger>
    
    <root>
        <level value="Info" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

What I want to achieve:

- Disable log messages I see in my Azure app-service (many HTTP GET and HTTP POST logs, probably coming from the IIS logs)
- Have DEBUG level logs of anything coming from `Microsoft.AspNetCore`

What am I missing? If I'm using log4net, do I still need the "Logging" section in the `appsettings.json` file? If I add the following, I will be able to see the logs, but why is it needed? Shouldn't this be controlled from the `log4net.conf` file?

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
     "Microsoft": "Debug"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The logging levels messages below the Information level for a development build you must make allowances for it in the `appsettings.Development.json` as specified in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-logging) and illustrated below:

```
{
     "Logging": {
         "LogLevel": {
             "Default": "Debug",
             "...":"..."
          }
     }
}
```

See  [here](https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore#logging-lower-than-the-information-level)

By default appsettings.json file will be generated in Asp.net core applications.

Logging configuration is commonly provided by the `Logging` section of *appsettings*.`{Environment}`*.json* files. *appsettings.Development.json* file is generated by the ASP.NET Core web app templates:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Debug",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
          }
     }
}
```

The logging categories are

If the `"default"` log level is not set, the default log level value is `Information.`

The `"Microsoft"` category logs at log level Debug and higher.

The `"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime"` category logs at log level "Information" and higher.

The log level follows:

`Trace` = 0, `Debug` = 1, `Information` = 2, `Warning` = 3, `Error` = 4, `Critical` = 5, and `None` = 6.

Refer [here for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-logging)

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55271929/15997690) for ***disable*** the IIS logs