# How do I fix 405 error when authenticating with [Authorize] attribute on a POST action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication

In an ASP.NET 6 MVC app I have implemented sign-in. If I'm signed in and my auth cookie expires or is deleted, running an HttpGet action reauthenticates me and I am taken to the desired page. All as expected.

However, if I run an HttpPost action while signed out but still on the page, I am taken to the Microsoft page to reauthenticate, I select my account, and then I get an HTTP ERROR 405 in my browser:

[image: This page isn’t working right now. If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405]

I couldn't find anything about this issue in my research. In fact, people are saying the [Authorize] attribute redirects them to the sign-in page in such cases, which would be a good solution for me.

Why am I getting a 405 when I run a HttpPost action with an [Authorize] attribute and how can I fix this?

Part of my Program.cs:

```
// ... other code ...

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>("Cookies", options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(builder.Configuration.GetValue<double>("AzureAd:TimeoutInMinutes"));
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.Name = "App.Cookie";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/UserAccess/Denied";
});

builder.Services.Configure(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, (Action<OpenIdConnectOptions>)(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnTicketReceived = context =>
    {
        // code validating user is allowed to sign-in
    };
}));

// ... other code ...
```

These are the logs I'm getting with Debug log level:

```
2023-06-14 09:45:10.7867 | INFO | IdentityLoggerAdapter.Log | Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter | IDX10239: Lifetime of the token is valid. | 
2023-06-14 09:45:10.7867 | INFO | IdentityLoggerAdapter.Log | Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter | IDX10234: Audience Validated.Audience: 'fc69a877-9376-46f8-a651-560w49pf0e96m' | 
2023-06-14 09:45:10.7867 | INFO | IdentityLoggerAdapter.Log | Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter | IDX10245: Creating claims identity from the validated token: '[PII of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. | 
2023-06-14 09:45:10.7867 | INFO | IdentityLoggerAdapter.Log | Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter | IDX10241: Security token validated. token: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. | 
2023-06-14 09:45:10.7867 | INFO | IdentityLoggerAdapter.Log | Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter | IDX21305: OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.ProtocolMessage.Code is null, there is no 'code' in the OpenIdConnect Response to validate. | 
2023-06-14 09:45:10.7867 | INFO | IdentityLoggerAdapter.Log | Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter | IDX21310: OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken is null, there is no 'token' in the OpenIdConnect Response to validate. | 
2023-06-14 09:45:10.7867 | INFO | LoggingExtensions.AuthenticationSchemeSignedIn | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler | AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in. | 
2023-06-14 09:45:10.8008 | INFO | Log.ExecutingEndpoint | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware | Executing endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported' | 
2023-06-14 09:45:10.8008 | INFO | Log.ExecutedEndpoint | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware | Executed endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported' |
```

Comment: Please use `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); ` to check the error details.  You also can [enable debug level logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68981170/7687666) or [enable ASP.NET Core Error Logging](https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1487/enabling-asp_net-core-error-logging.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for you response! I have edited my post to include relevant log messages, although they're only info level despite me setting it to debug. There does not appear to be an actual C# exception thrown.

Comment: Do you use `Authorize` without setting any properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a few solutions to the issue.

First solution is to add `services.AddRazorPages().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();` and `endpoints.MapRazorPages();` to Program.cs. This will enable the sign-out page provided by Microsoft and your app should redirect there on sign-out.

It should be enough to implement the first solution, but due to some routing configuration I use in my code, I needed to find another solution.

The second solution is to add your own sign-out action that, by default, redirects back to the home page. Here is the action I use:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SignOutUser()
{
    return SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```